# Custom Sorting gglot2 in python

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I am working on ggplt visualization, which plotting countries total expenditure from the highest to the lowest. Since there are many small values, I am aggregating several small categories into the "other" category. I am having trouble finding a way to move the "Other" Category to the end and keeping the rest sorted from in descending order

`

```
ggplot(df_sorted, aes(x = 'reorder(customer_country, Total_Expenditure, fun=sum)', y = 'Total_Expenditure', fill='Total_Expenditure'))\
    + geom_bar(stat="identity")\
        + scale_x_discrete()\
            + coord_flip()\
                +scale_fill_cmap(cmap_name="RdYlGn")
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDRPL.png)

Have Category Other at the bottom of the bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can custom sort your dataframe outside ggplot (just using some `pandas`) and no reordering inside the plot aesthetics will be necessary.

The code below demonstrates this for the `diamonds` dataset that comes with `plotline`, where one factor level ('Premium') is moved to the bottom while all others remain sorted.

*Side note:* Please include (at least a subset) of your actual dataframe in your next question for a fully reproducible example, or demonstrate the question/problem with a dataset provided by one of the libraries.

#### custom dataframe sorting

there is probably a more elegant way, but the important

```py
from plotnine.data import diamonds
import pandas as pd

# this takes the job of reorder(.., fun=sum) and creates a sorted list of the factor
df = diamonds.groupby('cut', as_index=False).aggregate({'carat': 'sum'})
sorted_levels = df.sort_values('carat')['cut']

# custom reordering of the factor level of interest, 
# here 'Premium' is moved to one end while the rest remains ordered
sorted_custom = ['Premium'] + [l for l in sorted_levels if not l == 'Premium']

# reorder dataframe based on these factor levels
df['cut'] = pd.Categorical(df['cut'], sorted_custom)
df = df.sort_values('cut')
```

#### plot (without further sorting)

```py
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar, scale_x_discrete, coord_flip, scale_fill_cmap
(
    ggplot(df, aes(x = 'cut', y = 'carat', fill='carat'))\
    + geom_bar(stat='identity')\
    + scale_x_discrete()\
    + coord_flip()\
    + scale_fill_cmap(cmap_name="RdYlGn")
)
```

[image]